# Spark web ui on mesos/dcos

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mesos, dcos

we have setup spark on a mesos/dcos cluster.

I can see my running spark streaming job at http://my_mesos_cluster/service/spark/, but I didn't found a way to get the web ui, which I got on when I run spark locally (localhost:4040)
I need it, to see information about how many events was proceeded in a batch, etc.

Whats the "spark web ui" url on a mesos/dcos cluster? Or what do I have to do, to enable the web ui?

Regards,
Markus

Comment: Do you have access to `mesos web ui`? you will find host of your application there.

Comment: Thx! Found it! 
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to avr!
Found the hostname in mesos web ui. This host with port 4040 shows to spark web ui.